# sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'c.created' in 'field list'"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Im getting this error which I'm not completely sure how to solve.

```
    CommentModel.getCommentsForPost = (postId) => {
    let baseSQL = `SELECT u.username, c.comment, c.created, c.id
    FROM comments c
    JOIN users u
    on u.id=fk_authorid
    WHERE c.fk_postid=?
    ORDER BY c.created DESC`;
    return db.query(baseSQL, [postId])
        .then(([results, fields]) => {
            return Promise.resolve(results);
        }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
};
```

Error:

```
      code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sql: 'SELECT u.username, c.comment, c.created, c.id\n' +
    '    FROM comments c\n' +
    '    JOIN users u\n' +
    '    on u.id=fk_authorid\n' +
    "    WHERE c.fk_postid='''1'''\n" +
    '    ORDER BY c.created DESC',
  sqlState: '42S22',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'c.created' in 'field list'"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the "comments" table actually has a "created" column? If yes, I'd suggest you try a simpler query like "SELECT id, created FROM comments" and see if it's able to find the "created" column or not.

Comment: Thanks! I did not actually have it created.